# Is there a single Apps Script function equivalent to MATCH() with TRUE?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to write some functions that involve the same function as the Sheets function MATCH() with parameter 'sort type' set to TRUE or 1, so that a search for 35 in [10,20,30,40] will yield 2, the index of 30, the next lowest value to 35.

I know I can do this by looping over the array to search, and testing each value against my search value until a value greater than the search value is found, but it seems to me there must be a shorthand way of doing this. We don't have to do this when seeking an exact value; we can just use indexOf(). I was surprised when I first learned that indexOf() does not have a parameter for search type, but can only return a -1 if an exact value is not found.

Is there no function akin to indexOf() that will do this, or is it actually necessary to loop over the array every time you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you're looking for the `array.find()` method. The impelentation could be something like this:

```js
var arr = [10,20,30,40]

// make a copy of the array, reverse it and do find with condition
var value = arr.slice().reverse().find(x => x < 35)

console.log(value) // output --> 30 (first element less than 35 in the reversed array)

var index = arr.indexOf(value)

console.log(index) // output --> 2 (index of the element in the original array)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

There is another method `array.findIndex()`. Probably you can use it as well:

```js
var arr = [10,20,30,40]

// find more or equal 35 and return previous index
var index = arr.findIndex(x => x >= 35) - 1 

console.log(index) // output --> 2
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfunko(tgt = 35) {
  Logger.log([10,20,30,40].reduce((a,c,i) => { a.r = (a.x >= c)? i:a.r;return a;},{x:tgt}).r)
}
```